# Cannot move monitors between monitors

Tags: nvidia, windows, multiple-monitors

I have 2 NVIDIA graphic cards installed in my desktop and I have connected 4 monitors to the machine.

I have activated and enabled all four at the correct resolution using the "NVIDIA X Server" GUI editor, but I can't move a window from 1 display to another.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not cross posting :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have since enabled Xinerama and can now move my windows around

Answer (score 0):

Are you using twinview mode?
If not and you are in the "multiple x server mode" you cannot move windows between your "screens"
because the represent multiple separate X-servers, that happen to share the same keyboard and mouse.

This is a limitation of how X works and cannot be fixed.

Comment: Does twinview join 2 monitors into a single virtual display? I may disable this if Xinerama is able to join the multiple x server modes into a shared desktop...