# possible to move windows between x-displays? Hopes lifted because bin/gimp can do this

Tags: gnome, windows, multiple-monitors

For the longest time I have been convinced that it is not possible to move windows between X displays, and this question has been asked a few times only to be shot down as here: [Cannot move monitors between monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84200/cannot-move-monitors-between-monitors)

But, I noticed a few days ago that if you use the 'gimp' program, each of the windows actually contains an option to move itself to any of the available X displays on your machine.

Anyone have an idea of what it's doing? Is it really destroying the window and creating a new one from scratch, or is there some hidden shell trick that can be extracted?

I[image: display magic ftw]

Answer (score 1):

I have just answered a similiar question here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1264401#p1264401

In short, this can be done at least in GTK. Although it depends on the application itself to do so, as written in Arch's wiki:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#Separate_screens

> With this configuration it is not possible to move windows between screens, apart from a few special programs like GIMP and Emacs which have multi-screen support.

Comment: ok so I guess it is not easily possible. What about this, can I make "switch desktop" be limited to only one of the screens in twinview mode? e.g. hitting cntrl-alt-right should only shift the current screen's desktop, not both twinview monitors.